# Error : package android.support.annotation. does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx

I will run the program, but there is an error as shown below

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I try:
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'

implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"

But not work
please give me a solution, thank you

[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nQA5.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nQA5.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6NvH.jpg)

Comment: Have you add google() in your top-level Gradle file?
`allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}`

Comment: google ()? where ?,

i have edited and added the top gradle image

Comment: I've added it google()

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: no it's the same

Comment: Try removing all the support libraries in your dependencies. In your case, they are _com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0_, _com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0_, _com.android.support:design:28.0.0_, and _com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0_. If need to, please replace with Android X Library in necessary cases.

Answer (score 0):

Android Support Libraries are available from Google's Maven Repository.
According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven), To add one of these libraries to your build, include Google's Maven repository in your top-level *build.gradle* file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        // add related repo
    }
    dependencies {
        // add classpath files here
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // add it here ...
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added it like the photo link above. but still an error.

Will using Android and Androidx at the same time cause an error?